# Warning with ompl

Tags: ros, beginner, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have updated my ros packages, now when I use `catkin_make` or run certain nodes, I obtain:

```
WARNING: Package "ompl" does not follow the version conventions. It should not contain leading zeros (unless the number is 0).
```

There is a way to fix this warning?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206234/warning-with-ompl/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That warning is really just a warning, and has no influence on the correct functioning of OMPL, MoveIt or any package/node making use of it.

See also @isucan's answer in [Package "ompl" does not follow the version conventions](http://answers.ros.org/question/187313/package-ompl-does-not-follow-the-version-conventions/):

> For historical reasons, the convention for the OMPL version is non-standard: https://github.com/ros-gbp/ompl-release/blob/master/read_this_before_releasing

> This was done so that we have unique version numbers and can release OMPL for ROS outside of the regular OMPL release cycle. In the meantime things have stabilized much more, so I think we could start adopting a standard version. That said, we should probably switch to the debian package for OMPL directly (although, even for indigo, that is a bit old now).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-03-30**:
Thanks! Like it says in the Answer of the link that you posted, "Try linking against ${OMPL_LIBRARIES} instead of ${ompl_LIBRARIES}" solved the problem.